# Compute an upper bound on generalized eigenvalues (by using the coefficients)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, estimation

Consider the generalized, symmetric eigenvalueproblem:
\begin{equation}
 A x = \lambda B x,
\end{equation}
with $A, B$ symmetric and $B$ being positive definite.

For some computations, i was trying to figure out an upper bound for the generalized eigenvalues of this problem by using the coefficients. By taking a proper matrix norm $\| \cdot\|$, you get
\begin{equation}
 |\lambda| = \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|Bx\|} \leq \frac{\|A\| \|x\|}{\|Bx\|}.
\end{equation}
The enumerator can be estimated simple, for example by taking a normed eigenvector $x$ with $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ (the sup-norm, i.e. you just have to add some absolute values of the matrix entries to bound that part). But what should i do with the denominator?

**Edit:** as mentioned by Algebraic Pavel's or user161825's answer, you could do that by estimating the smallest eigenvalue $\mu_1$ of $B$ by some $0 < \bar{\mu} < \mu_{1}$, but how do you get this $\bar{\mu}$ just by knowing the coefficients of $B$? Of course - for computations - trying to invert the Matrix $B$ isn't feasible, are there smart ways to get this bound?

One possible answer could be using the neat [Gershgorin-circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), but this can only be applied to special cases of $B$, namely when $B$ is **strict diagonal dominant**. Then you could iterate over all rows $k$ and, depending on the sign of the diagonal entry $B_{k,k}$ (let's here assume it's positive), you can calculate $\displaystyle \xi_k = B_{k,k} -  \sum_{\substack{i=1, \\ i \neq k}}^{n} | B_{k,i} | $. In the end you just take the minimal $\xi_k$ over $1 \leq k \leq n$ and got your lower estimate for the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem $Ax=\lambda Bx$ is equivalent to $B^{-1}Ax=\lambda x$, so the generalized eigenvalues are the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A\sim B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$. Hence the eigenvalues can be bounded from above by *any* norm of $B^{-1}A$, e.g.,
$$
|\lambda|\leq\|B^{-1}A\|_2,\quad|\lambda|\leq\|B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}\|_2,\quad \text{etc.}
$$
Note that the latter inequality is sharper since $\|B^{-1}A\|_2\geq\|B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}\|_2$ (still assuming that $B$ is SPD).
Of course, if the chosen matrix norm is submultiplicative, you can take out $B$ and get
$$
|\lambda|\leq\|A\|\|B^{-1}\|.
$$

Another simple bound can be obtained as follows:
$$Ax=\lambda Ax\quad\Rightarrow\quad x^TAx=\lambda x^TBx\quad\Rightarrow\quad\lambda=\frac{x^TAx}{x^TBx}.$$
Hence
$$
|\lambda|=\frac{|x^TAx|}{x^TBx}=\left|\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}\right|\frac{x^Tx}{x^TBx}
\leq\max_{y\neq 0}\left|\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty}\right|\max_{z\neq 0}\frac{z^Tz}{z^TBz}
=\frac{\max_{y\neq 0}\left|\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty}\right|}{\min_{z\neq 0}\frac{z^TBz}{z^Tz}}
=\frac{|\lambda_{\max}(A)|}{\lambda_{\min}(B)}.
$$
Note that since the matrices $A$ and $B$ are symmetric  and $B$ is SPD, this bound is equal again to $\|A\|_2\|B^{-1}\|_2$.

Comment: Yeah, that's true (as well as in @user161825 's answer). I'm sorry, but maybe i didn't mention it clear enough that i'm looking for a bound in terms of *computation*, i.e. i have two matrices $A$ and $B$ on my computer and want an upper bound for the generalized eigenvalues $| \lambda |$ by (for example) using the coefficients of the matrices. For a simple eigenvalueproblem $A x = \lambda x$ you could just add up the absolute values of $A$ for such a bound, but here i'm trying to find out something similar for the generalized case.

Comment: @ハンバーガー When $B$ is large, getting a (nontrivial) lower bound on $\lambda_{\min}(B)$ is not an easy task. In the "lucky" case when $B$ is diagonally dominant, a bound can be obtained using the Geršgorin theorem. Otherwise, you would normally need to use methods based on inverse iteration (note that you don't need to compute $B^{-1}$ explicitly but it is sufficient to do it implicitly via a suitable (in this case, Cholesky) factorization).

Comment: That's funny, i was thinking about the Geršgorin theorem at the same time too (and even put it in the edit). But sadly my matrices $B$ are mass matrices, arising from solving PDEs approximately. In all cases i've computed so far, the diagonal entry is exactly the same as summing up the absolute values of the other entries in that row - i assume that's a normal behaviour or mass matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b>0$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $B$. Then $b^2>0$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $B^2$. It follows that $\langle (B^2-b^2I)x,x\rangle\geq 0$, or equivalently $\|B x\|\geq b\|x\|$.

Alternatively, rewrite your equation as
$$
B^{-1}Ax=\lambda x,
$$
which implies $|\lambda|\leq \|B^{-1}A\|$. Of course $b=\|B^{-1}\|^{-1}$, so this result implies  $|\lambda|\leq \|A\|/b$, as above.

As for computing a lower bound for the lowest eigenvalue, [this](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/bndseigs80.pdf) may be an interesting read. Inspired by formula 2.54 there, let us assume that $b_1\geq\ldots\geq b_n$ are the non-increasingly ordered eigenvalues of $B$, counted with multiplicity. Observe that
$$
\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} b_j\leq \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} b_j^{n-1}}{n-1}<\frac{\mbox{tr }(B^{n-1})}{n-1},
$$
so that
$$
b_n=\frac{\mbox{det }B}{\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} b_j}> \frac{(n-1)\mbox{det }B}{\mbox{tr }(B^{n-1})}>0
$$
when $n>1$.

This leaves us with the following (probably poor) estimate
$$
|\lambda|< \frac{\|A\|\mbox{tr }(B^{n-1})}{(n-1)\mbox{det }B}.
$$

Comment: The article sure looks interesting, the trace-approach could be fertile - i have to look a bit more into that. But yeah, estimating $\det B$ from below is most likely as difficult as estimating the lowest eigenvalue of $B$ from below…

Comment: The determinant can be computed explicitly using only the entries of the matrix, with only [$O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computing_determinants) (I guess the same is true for the inverse). What are your precise conditions for something to be 'computable in terms of the coefficients'?

Comment: I'm dealing with large, sparse matrices, so calculating determinants or factoring matrices isn't feasible anymore. Usually my matrices are around dimension 1 million or bigger. So, "computable in terms of the coefficients", could be something that's looking at every entry in my matrix once (here, i only need to look at the non-zero entries). For example a good method for simple eigenvalue problems, $Ax = \lambda x$, is $|\lambda| \leq \|A\|_{\infty}$. With that you only need to compute the maximum absolute row sum of the matrix, which is rather cheap to get.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this mean that even multiplying matrices is 'too hard'?

Comment: Not at all of the matrix is *sparse*, i.e. you can bound the non-zero entries of every row and column with a constant. Then, for a matrix-vector-multiplication, you only need to iterate over all non-zero entries of the sparse matrix, i.e. you got a $O(n)$-complexity ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15693610/3935294). About multiplying two sparse matrices, im not sure, but with some extra structure in the way you store the matrix in your computer, there should be a fast way to do it too.